# Possible Memory Issue on DialogFragment Initialization?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have seen some people use the code below. To initialize and call a fragment.

### FIRST WAY

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = manager.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }

DialogFragment newFragment = YourFragmentDialog.newInstance();
newFragment.show(ft, "yourTag");
```

### SECOND WAY

```
DialogFragment newFragment = YourFragmentDialog.newInstance();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "yourTag");
```

**I have 3 questions:**

1. Is the first way necessary?
2. Is the second approach would cause a memory leak?
3. After a `DialogFragment` is canceled or dismissed. Would it be garbage collected automatically or should we explicitly set it to `null`?

Comment: Correct way to use Dialog Fragments https://github.com/kenodoggy/FragmentSamples/tree/master/DialogFragment/app/src/main/java/com/kenodoggy/dialogfragment The repo has examples of master-detail flow, navDrawer and viewPager too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to show your [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) which will properly remove & replace any currently showing dialog with new one, from the official [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog).you can go through it for understanding the right way to implement it.use [`getSupportFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager%28%29) for better.Just avoid these type of confusions by following official docs.

```
void showDialog() {
    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```